# MFC Document/view Order of construction?

Tags: view, mfc, document

i have a problem i want my sdi mfc program to display a document at startup , the problem is the order of construction , since i display the doc through the view class, the order here is relevant. How can i overcome this issue ? think about when an application starts with the most recent document already opened.
Thanks , hope to be clear

Comment: Were is the problem? Why is the sequence relevant? The Document is created first... the view and frame is created after the document. Because the view requires a document I see no problem in the construction sequence...

Comment: In the view's code, you can always assume that the document exists. Check the value of GetDocument() against NULL for verification. But still, a view is always supposed to display its document, or modify it, so I don't see where the problem is. And in SDI applications, there is always ONE document instance created. A suggestion, do not perform such initializations in the constructors of the document or class, instead use another member, or create a (one-time only) timer - it will fire just before your apps enters the idle state ("yields");

Comment: I have a scintilla control embedded in the view, when the app starts i'd like to load a text into the scintilla calling the relevant function in the view class FROM the main, the problem is that the view hasn't been created when the mainframe starts, i tried to move the code in the doc but the problem still persists.I am not an mfc expert i'd like to know how the problem is solved or if there is something i am missing

Answer (score 1):

When the document has been created and after the View is created you receive an call to `CView::OnInitialUpdate`. (See your virtual functions)

Override the function. Get you document pointer with GetDocument and now load the data into your Scintilla control.

Comment: Didn't work, i have tried storing the file name to load and i get a null string, i have a bit of confusion  about what is created after what.

Comment: What didn't worked? OnInitialUpdate is called when everything is ready to be shown... everything is created...

Comment: For some reasons , the scintilla control crashes when oninitialupdate is called, the correct way should be to initialize in the OnCreate event not on the OnInitialUpdate, i have found a convoluted way to walk around this problem but its ugly

Comment: What is the problem. Initializing and loading data ist something different. Sure. Scintilla must be created in the view may be in OnCreate...  but again: What is your problem?

Comment: Ok, problem, i want that the scintilla control at startup to show a txt file. My main problem is that i do not know how to pass the file to load as a string during the document-mainframe-view creation, i tried every combination, but the problem still persist. I see lots of programs capable of showing the mos recent project previously saved, i just do not know how to do it.

Comment: You can create the scintilla control and later pass the data to it... don't stuck at create and load...

Comment: The Scintilla control must be created In the OnCreate function, anyways i solved the problem , its ugly but at least it works for now